# How to toggle multi-line comments with vim mode in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code, on a Mac, using the Vim emulation.

If I have a `.py` file like this:

```py
test1 = 1

test2 = 2
```

And I select all three lines, then press `<cmd>` and `/` I get this:

```py
# test1 = 1

# test2 = 2
```

I would like the same functionality using a vim command sequence of `<leader>`, then `c`, then `<space>`.

In my `settings.json` I have this:

```
{
  "vim.leader": ",",
  "vim.normalModeKeyBindings": [
    {
      "before": ["<leader>", "c", "<space>"],
      "commands": ["editor.action.commentLine"],
      "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    }
  ]
}
```

But, using that sequence, while I can select a single line to toggle commenting on/off, it does nothing when I have multiple lines selected. Why?

Answer (score 5):

Please try adding the following to your settings.json and let me know if it works for you. It worked for me.

```
"vim.visualModeKeyBindings": [
  {
    "before": ["<leader>", "c"],
    "commands": ["editor.action.commentLine"],
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
  }
],
```

Comment: btw, I used <leader> "c" , you'll have to use <leader> , "c", "space"

Comment: That does it, thanks Ken! I still need the same thing within the `"vim.normalModeKeyBindings"` section to have it work for single-line comments, but with this addition it's all working as I hoped!